# Play button does not change color if I enlarge the screen libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using FitViewport so that my "play" and "options" buttons do not change size when I enlarge the game window. I also created the PLAY_ACTIVE button in blue and PLAY_INACTIVE in red. These two work, but if I maximize the window, the color doesn't change. For example, when the pointer is on "play", it changes color but when I widen the screen and then put the pointer on play, it doesn't change color.

My code:

1)Main:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;

import com.mygdx.game.screen.MainMenuScreen;

public class NameGame extends Game {

public static final int WIDTH = 900;
public static final int HEIGHT = 780;

public SpriteBatch batch;

private OrthographicCamera camera;
private FitViewport viewport;

@Override
public void create() {  //Apertura app
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(800, 800, camera);
    camera.position.set(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2,0);
    camera.update();
    
    
    this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this)); //Visualizza menu
}

@Override
public void render(){  //Esecuzione app
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    super.render();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height){  
    viewport.update(width,height);
    super.resize(width, height);
}
```

}

2)MainMenuScreen:

```
package com.mygdx.game.screen;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

import com.mygdx.game.NameGame;

public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen{
    
    
    private static final int PLAY_BUTTON_WIDTH = 140;
    private static final int PLAY_BUTTON_HEIGHT = 62;
    private static final int OPTIONS_BUTTON_WIDTH = 140;
    private static final int OPTIONS_BUTTON_HEIGHT = 60;
    private static final int PLAY_BUTTON_Y = 100;
    private static final int OPTIONS_BUTTON_Y = 30;
    
    NameGame game;
    
    Texture playButtonActive;
    Texture playButtonInactive;
    Texture optionsButtonActive;
    Texture optionsButtonInactive;
    
    public MainMenuScreen (NameGame game){
        
        this.game = game;
        
        playButtonActive = new Texture("play1.png");
        playButtonInactive = new Texture("play2.png");
        optionsButtonActive = new Texture("options1.png");
        optionsButtonInactive = new Texture("options2.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float f) {  
        
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        game.batch.begin();
        
        
        //Play
        int x = NameGame.WIDTH / 2 - PLAY_BUTTON_WIDTH / 2 ;
        if(Gdx.input.getX() < x + PLAY_BUTTON_WIDTH && Gdx.input.getX() > x && NameGame.HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY() < PLAY_BUTTON_Y + PLAY_BUTTON_HEIGHT && NameGame.HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY() > PLAY_BUTTON_Y){
            game.batch.draw(playButtonActive, x, PLAY_BUTTON_Y, PLAY_BUTTON_WIDTH, PLAY_BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        } else {
            game.batch.draw(playButtonInactive, NameGame.WIDTH/2 - PLAY_BUTTON_WIDTH/2, PLAY_BUTTON_Y, PLAY_BUTTON_WIDTH, PLAY_BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        }
        //Options
        game.batch.draw(optionsButtonInactive, NameGame.WIDTH/2 - OPTIONS_BUTTON_WIDTH/2, OPTIONS_BUTTON_Y, OPTIONS_BUTTON_WIDTH, OPTIONS_BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        
    game.batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }
}
```

Comment: You don’t have any buttons at all. You just have some Textures that you called buttons. Read in the official libGDX documentation about Scene2D and Scene2D.ui.

Comment: I mean images of buttons. The image don't change color when i resize the screen

Comment: Input needs to be based on position relative to the camera, not hard coded Constanta. But why reinvent the wheel? There is a Button class you can use.

Comment: Do you mean gdx.input? Maybe I complicated the situation. Can I use the button class? Sorry i'm new on libgdx

Comment: Trying to create each button at the top level using manual positioning, drawing, swapping the texture, etc. is going to explode in complexity once you start adding more than one of them to your game. This is what classes in OOP are for. You can create your own Button class to handle this, or you can use the built-in one provided by libGDX. The built-in one should be used as part of a Stage so all the input targeting and handling is done for you. But it's not completely trivial. You'll have to read through the documentation to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons won't change the color, because the coordinates are wrong. The [getX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#getX--) and [getY](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#getY--) methods of [Gdx.input](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html) will return the screen coordinates:

> The x coordinate of the last touch on touch screen devices and the current mouse position on desktop for the first pointer **in screen coordinates**. The screen origin is the top left corner.

Since you want the **world coordinates** instead of the **screen coordinates** you need to [unproject](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#unproject-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-) the position of the mouse on the screen according to the camera:

```
Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
// change screen coordiates to world coordinates by using the camera.unproject method
Vector3 unprojectedMousePosition = game.camera.unproject(mousePosition); 

// check the position in world coordinates
if(unprojectedMousePosition.x < x + PLAY_BUTTON_WIDTH && unprojectedMousePosition.x > x && NameGame.HEIGHT - unprojectedMousePosition.y < PLAY_BUTTON_Y + PLAY_BUTTON_HEIGHT && NameGame.HEIGHT - unprojectedMousePosition.y > PLAY_BUTTON_Y){
    game.batch.draw(playButtonActive, x, PLAY_BUTTON_Y, PLAY_BUTTON_WIDTH, PLAY_BUTTON_HEIGHT);
} else {
    game.batch.draw(playButtonInactive, NameGame.WIDTH/2 - PLAY_BUTTON_WIDTH/2, PLAY_BUTTON_Y, PLAY_BUTTON_WIDTH, PLAY_BUTTON_HEIGHT);
}

// ...
```